# Batch add quotes around 2 adjacent letters

Tags: windows, batch-file, replace, cmd

So I want to search a text file for 2 adjacent letters.
The text file would be in this format

```
a
b
c
d
e
```

But if there was say `aa`, I would want to add "" around it so it would end up being `"aa"`.
Preferably using batch.
Also, if it happened to be `xz`, the result would be `"xz"`, I could do this with a simple find and replace, but it would require 676 different scenarios so is there an easier way?

Comment: Your request is not clear. Can the file contain lines with one or two letters only? If  not, please describe the others cases and the desired result.

Comment: The file has 1 or 2 characters per line, all of which are letters of the english alphabet

Comment: @Paul there are 25 letters in the english alphabet and there are 1 or 2 characters per line. If there's only 1 I need nothing done. If there's 2 there are 625 different possibilites for it(it could be "aa""ab""ac" all the way to "zz" 25^2 or 25 squared) http://bit.ly/1RPEprA

Comment: @Jokru You mean `26^2` not `25^2` which it give `sqr(26)=676`

Comment: Oh yeah sorry, I subtracted from the scandinavian alphabet and must've messed up there, my bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off

(
echo a
echo c
echo cd
echo def
echo e
echo fg
echo efg
echo xz1
echo xz123
echo xz14
)>_list.tmp

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F %%i in (_list.tmp) do ( 
  set "str=%%i"
  if "!str:~1!" EQU "" (echo !str!) else if "!str:~2!" EQU "" (echo "!str!") else ( echo !str! )
)
exit /b 0
```

output

```
a
c
"cd"
def
e
"fg"
efg
xz1
xz123
xz14
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you alot, now is there an easy way to replace the original file with this, I could probably figure out a way, but yours will probably be better

Comment: @Jokru If you need to use regex in batch, sed is a good solution, you can find it in GnuWin32 at sourceforge. Also there JREPL.bat hybrid batch http://superuser.com/questions/975704/edit-lines-in-txt-file-with-bat/

Answer (score 0):

Use capturing group.

```
sed 's/\([a-z]\{2\}\)/"\1"/g' file
```

or

```
sed 's/[a-z]\{2\}/"&"/g' file
```

Example:

```
$ echo 'ad b dd fg' | sed 's/[a-z]\{2\}/"&"/g'
"ad" b "dd" "fg"
```

Comment: I need all of the alphabet x-z covered, does that do it?

Comment: ya, `[a-z]` covers all lowercase alphabets, if you want both upper and lower cases then change `[a-z]` to `[A-Za-z]`

Comment: sed isn't recognized?

Comment: Do I need to install something? Currently I don't have anything related to regex

Comment: what's wrong with sed? You may install perl. THis regex should also works on perl too.

Comment: When I run your command, it just says `sed couldn't be recognized as an internal or external command`

Comment: Ok now I have sed working, but it just prints the text file and does nothing else with `sed s/\([a-zA-Z]\{2\}\)/"\1"/g "all.txt"`

Comment: The answer works fine here. Anyway, if you're on Unix, maybe you can also try `perl -pe 's/([a-z]{2})/"$1"/ig' data`. Or on windows, fire up Notepad++ and do like this: [link](http://pasteboard.co/MIu5QbI.png)

Answer (score 0):

If "The file has 1 or 2 characters per line, all of which are letters of the english alphabet" and you want to "add quotes around 2 adjacent letters", then you really want to add quotes to lines that have 2 characters, don't matter which characters they are, isn't it?

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Process all file lines
for /F "delims=" %%a in (input.txt) do (
   set "line=%%a"
   rem If the line have just one character
   if "!line:~1!" equ "" (
      rem Show the same line
      echo %%a
   ) else (
      rem Enclose the two chars in quotes
      echo "%%a"
   )
)
```

Comment: That is perfect, but now I just need the original file replaced with that edit